# 3M Caulk Remover

Tags: caulking

Does anybody have experience with 3M Caulk Remover? I read about it at Cool Tools (a great site, by the way):

http://www.kk.org/cooltools/archives/000926.php

If you read the comments, some people love it, and some had problems with it. Can anybody suggest a better product? I have some old, blackened caulk at the back of my stainless steel kitchen sink, and I want to replace it.

Comment: By definition 3M has good products and never had any problems with them in any area, home, car, school. etc. This should be fine and wont damage your stainless steel. Use a plastic scrapper to gently remove the caulk.

Comment: @andrewl, are you skilled with a utility knife or scrapping tool? If yes, I would use one of those tools to cutaway, scrape away the old caulk. Then use some kind of non-scratch cleaning pad with warm soapy water to wash the area down (rinse with clean water afterwards).

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use this product. Its easy to remove caulk by hand. In only a few cases does it really need to be completely gone, such as for painting and significant fixture changes. Usually caulk is removed and then immediately covered back up with new caulk.

I would use a plastic scraper to get the caulk up. For stubborn or detailed work use a new, clean razorblade. After the big bits are up, hit it mildly abrasive kitchen cleaner and a scrubby/rough-texture sponge to get the last little bits and adhesive up. Wipe it dry and put down new caulk.

Use the $6 you saved on the caulk remover to buy yourself lunch.